# If/else in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I know this might sound silly, but I want to know if there is a way like this to use.

My code is:

```
print(a (+=) if a==1 else (-=) b)
```

What I want it to do is,

```
if a==1:
    print(a+b) 
else:
    print(a-b)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course.

```
print(a+b if a==1 else a-b)
```

The word you're looking for is [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator).

Comment: if amountPaid.group(1):
        shelfFile[str(name)+'balance']+=float(amountPaid.group(2))
    else:
        shelfFile[str(name)+'balance']-=float(amountPaid.group(2)). This is the actual code, so if I do the above that would produce a large line.

Comment: `shelfFile[str(name)+'balance']+=float(amountPaid.group(2)) if amountPaid.group(1) else shelfFile[str(name)+'balance']-=float(amountPaid.group(2))` :)

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the length of the code?

Comment: if it is difficult to read of too long, using the ternary notation, you should use a traditional multiline if / else, to improve readability

Comment: In that case, it's better to put it on four lines for readability's sake.

Comment: Thanks, I should concentrate more on readability :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the ternary condition operator:

```
a = a + b if a == 1 else a - b
```

If `a == 1` is true, then a will hold the result of `a + b`, else it will hold the result of `a - b`

Demo:

```
a = 4
b = 2

# a should equal to 2
a = a + b if a == 1 else a - b
```

---

```
a = 1
b = 2

# a should equal to 3
a = a + b if a == 1 else a - b
```

Comment: if amountPaid.group(1):
        shelfFile[str(name)+'balance']+=float(amountPaid.group(2))
    else:
        shelfFile[str(name)+'balance']-=float(amountPaid.group(2)). This is the actual code, so if I do the above that would produce a large line.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas :)

Comment: @DeepakKrishna You are welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you as it indicates to other readers what you found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = a+b if a==1 else a-b
```

is the sane and reasonable person's approach, so here's the less sane version that more directly selects the *operation*, not the complete *expression* including operands, removing the need to repeat the operands in two places:

```
from operator import iadd, isub  # Like to += and -=, but you need to assign return

a = (iadd if a == 1 else isub)(a, b)
```

or even more concise/insane using `bool`s to index a `tuple`:

```
a = (isub, iadd)[a == 1](a, b)
```

To be clear, this is silly. Just use `a = a+b if a==1 else a-b`.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me many options to use in future :)